# Which Queue to Join at the Super Market

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, optimization, queueing-theory

Last night I started wonder about the fastest way to take a shopping trip with my university flat mates and was wonder about how we should queue for the check out. I have a feeling that queue theory plus some optimisation can answer my question, but don't know much about queue theory. So, here's my question:

Me and my friends are at the super market (lets say there are n of us). We are all ready to check out. Lets say there are m check outs. We can see how long the line is at each check out, it's l_i. We can calculate some statistical information (distribution of processing time for each check out).

Which queues should we join to get everyone out of the super market the quickest?

Comment: I shall wait for answers ! Every time I select a queue, thinking that it will be the fastest, it happens that it is in fact the slowest. So, I am quite anxious to know ! Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the mean processing time of checkout $C_i$ by $\mu_i$ $\>(1\leq i\leq m)$. Then we have to minimize
$$\max\bigl\{ \mu_i(\ell_i+x_i)\ \bigm|\ 1\leq i\leq m, \ x_i>0\bigr\}$$ under the constraints
$$x_i\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq0} \ (1\leq i\leq m),\qquad\sum_{i=1}^m x_i=n\ .$$

Comment: This is what I originally thought of, but then I got to wondering if you should include more information about the distribution of processing time. Now come to think of it I guess that's only relevant if I wanted to try to get everyone through at around the same time.